# Ubuntu 19.10 login screen changed after XDRP installation

Tags: ubuntu, remote, rdp

I installed xrdp in Ubuntu Linux as this:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

It worked fine and I can connect via rdp remote, the big problem is that previously after install xdrp the main login screen when I connect directly to the computer without rdp, I had my background screen and I logged with my user name, after install xdrp all that was replaced by the blue background with a mouse of the xdrp and also I cannot login normally as I was doing. Now I have access only to the computer via xdrp only, How can I restore my login screen, not the xdrp login screen, I mean when I enter directly in the computer because now it was replaced by xdrp background photo and everything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

run this command inside recovery mode 
or

run inside tty3

press `ctl+Alt +F3`  to login in tty3

Comment: I have access to terminal ssh and also to rdp but only that two because check photo I can’t select even another user inside the login of Ubuntu. I gave the command to install lightdm and it says I have installed the latest version. The problem is that it was fine. The situation started when I just installed xrdp and the xrdp replaced its own login. Look photo: https://imgur.com/17TpTAv

Comment: Another thing. I gave the command “ lightdm --show-config ” and the results where https://imgur.com/vbi4TxC

Comment: try to install another dm ---> sudo apt-get install xdm